# FetchRequest not updated with most recent record added to Core Data

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest

Every time my app runs it generates data that is stored in a core data entity "Entity". The result of my fetch request does not update with this most recent data, except if I exit the app and relaunch it again. I thought the "shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects" property would fix this issue but apparently not. My current fetch request code is the following:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"Entity"    inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_time" ascending:YES];
NSArray *Descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:Descriptors];

NSArray *historyDataArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:Nil];
```

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController does what you want.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail? Cannot be done using NSFetchRequest? thx.

Comment: NSFetchRequest can't be updated by itself. Check standard CoreData template to see how it's done.

Comment: @Shmidt, just found a simple way that will work using NSFetchRequest. When the new records are generated they are also stored in an array. If the array is empty (app was just launched), the fetch request is executed and used to feed historyDataArray, otherwise the array is used to feed historyDataArray.

Comment: Hey @user3662579.. I am facing the same issue.  Did you by any chance got to know what was the issue and if Yes , solution for the same